# Abnormally high accuracies with XGBoost

Tags: r, classification, weka, xgboost

I've recently started using XGBoost (via R's MLR package) to compare my results with the SMO algorithm (via Weka).

The task is a binary classification task to predict whether an individual has a high level or low level of a certain personality trait (example: high extraversion OR low extraversion).

I'm using a dataset with 300 instances and approximately 19000 features. The reason for the large number of feature is because the classification task is based on mostly n-grams as features.

After selecting and omitting some features, I managed to obtain 79% as my highest accuracy on Weka's SMO.
But running the XGBoost algorithm with the same set of features resulted in 98% accuracy.
Both algorithms are evaluated with 10-fold cross validation.

I know that XGBoost has proven to outperform many algorithms in different cases on Kaggle, but is it normal to have such a high difference in accuracies between SMO and XGBoost?

Here's the code for running XGBoost with 10-fold cross evaluation in R:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))

library(mlr)

train <- read.csv("AGREEABLENESS [10-DATASET].arff.csv", na.strings = c(""," ",NA))

train$class <- as.factor(train$class)

trainTask <- makeClassifTask(data=train, target="class")

set.seed(1001)

require(xgboost)
xg_set <- makeLearner("classif.xgboost", predict.type="prob")
xg_set$par.vals <- list(
objective="binary:logistic",
eval_metric="error",
nrounds=20
)

set_cv <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters=10L)

r = resample(learner = xg_set, task = trainTask, resampling = set_cv, measures = list(acc, tpr, ppv), show.info=TRUE)

r$aggr
```

Comment: This is more for stats SE as it concerns the methodlogy rather than programming that looks sound. The boosted methods do work rather well, but have a look at other statistics - recall, AUC? And is the dataset balanced?

Comment: All the other statistics are actually pretty close to the accuracy (0.9878788). Here are the results from other statistics: 
AUC: 0.9996296
Recall: 0.9739087
Precision: 1.0000000

The dataset size for each class is 150 for class 1 and 179 for class 2.

Comment: "... a dataset with 300 instances and approximately 19000 features" (!) I would expect 100% accuracy (grin). I think it may have been John von Neumann who said with four variables I can fit an elephant but with five variables I can make its trunk wiggle as well. What would he have made of 19000 variables?